# Calculating the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Calculate the real and imaginary parts of the holomorphic function $f(z)=z^2\cos(z)-e^{z^3-z}$ and verify directly that each of these functions is harmonic.

I believe I know how to the question, however I'm finding it quite tedious and I'm not confident in my work. I have tried substituting $z=x+iy$ and separating the components into real and imaginary parts, but I'm left with an ugly equation (which I'm not sure how to separate). Is there any easier way? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're doing the right thing. It won't be pretty. Remember that $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin How do I separate cos(x+iy) into its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Write it out in terms of exponentials: $\cos z = (e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$. $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ will enter stage left.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Thanks A lot I get it now!